# ReLinking with new collections

Tags: linked-data

I have a .blend file with animations for a given set of rigs. But lately I've just made changes with additions like FACE IT, which have a separate rig, also I've changed how files are organized inside collections.

Rig is working from the "mother" file, but I don't have the FACE IT rig, I know I can manage it to work, but I like to have the same collection, and objects hierarchy like in the "mother" file. Also I'm using "Animation Layers" addon, and that's why I don't want to make new file, because I have like 30 animations or more stacked, in a new file I must do it again, which I don't want to.

Is there any solution to fix it so that I will have new collections, that additional FACE IT rig, etc, in the same file?